# os.chdir() doesn't work with mpi4py spawning

Tags: python, parallel-processing, mpi, mpi4py

I have a small test code that acts as a task farm. The idea is that a list of tasks will be sent to a group of processes spawned by mpi4py, which will in turn change to a run directory and spawn an mpi-executable in that directory before returning, and retrieving a new task.

The problem is that the execution of mpi-executable seems to happen in the top level directory where the original program has been run.

The master code is executed in /top/level/folder/

and contains a list of tasks, e.g: [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]. The slaves each receive a task and change to a directory of the same name, before executing the mpi-executable, and then changing back.

The master code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from mpi4py import MPI
import numpy as np
import sys
import os
import time


comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD
rank = MPI.COMM_WORLD.Get_rank()

processes=4

tasks=([StopIteration] * (processes))+[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

new_comm=comm.Spawn("/path/to/slave/slave.py",
                  args=[],maxprocs=processes)

status=MPI.Status()

while tasks:
    new_comm.recv(source=MPI.ANY_SOURCE, status=status)
    data=tasks.pop()
    print("on master received source: ",status.Get_source())
    print("On master sending: ",data," to:",status.Get_source())
    new_comm.send(obj=data,dest=status.Get_source())
    print("On master sent: ",data," to:",status.Get_source())


print("Finished All",rank)
new_comm.Barrier()
print("after barrier",rank)
print("rank", rank,"task",tasks)
new_comm.Disconnect()
```

and the slave.py code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from mpi4py import MPI
import numpy as np
import sys
import os
import time

comm = MPI.Comm.Get_parent()
rank = comm.Get_rank()
cwd=os.getcwd()

print("slave", rank," entering loop")
for task in iter(lambda: comm.sendrecv(dest=0), StopIteration):
    print("slave ", rank," recvd data", task)
    print("slave ", rank," going to sleep")
    directory=os.path.join(cwd,str(task))
    os.chdir(directory)
    new_comm=MPI.COMM_SELF.Spawn("/path/to/some/mpi-executable",
                  args=[],maxprocs=4)
    os.chdir(cwd)
    new_comm.Barrier()
    new_comm.Free()


comm.Barrier()
comm.Disconnect()
```

But each instance of the  mpi-executable is trying to launch in /top/level/folder/

Any ideas as to why this behaviour is happening would be appreciated!

Comment: Consult the documentation of the underlying MPI implementation if it supports an option passed to MPI_Spawn to control the execution directory and the if the python wrapper allows to pass it down. Or just send the working directory after the spawn call and let the process do the change for itself - this would even be implementation indepedent.

Comment: Hey Georg - thanks for the input. There is no way to pass the directory through with the mpi4py spawn call, as far as I can see. I do change the working directory after the first spawn - as you can see in slave.py. It's this change that isn't taking place. Or rather when I print the cwd it looks like it has changed folder, but spawning again seems to happen above in the top level folder where the original script was run. The mpi-executable I am calling in the slave.py script is fortran90, and I don't want to start adding stuff to try and change the folder in there. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`MPI_COMM_SPAWN`, the MPI operation that `MPI.Comm.Spawn` is built on, takes an `MPI_INFO` object that can be used to supply additional implementation-specific information. The argument can also be supplied in `mpi4py` as the named `info` argument.

```
info = MPI.Info.Create()
info.Set('key', 'value')
MPI.Comm.Spawn(..., info=info, ...)
```

With many of the existing MPI implementations the info key for setting the working directory of the child processes is `wdir`.

Comment: That's what I only faintly remembered!

Comment: Yep - thanks guys, lovely stuff. Lisandro Dalcin on the mpi4py google group pointed out the same to me.